# How can I use mvim to edit my crontab on Mac OS X (10.6.6)

Tags: macos, vim, macvim

`mvim` is installed in `/usr/local/bin/` but can not be used as either `EDITOR` or `VISUAL`:

```
$ mvim -f # works as expected

$ EDITOR="/usr/local/bin/mvim -f" crontab -e
crontab: /usr/local/bin/mvim -f: No such file or directory
crontab: "/usr/local/bin/mvim -f" exited with status 1
```

I tried single quotes and using `VISUAL` instead of `EDITOR`. Same result. I also tried googling, but apparently the `-f` flag works just fine for everybody else.

I use Mac OS 10.6.6 and zsh, but the problem is the same in bash.

Comment: Have you tried just escaping the space? `EDITOR=/usr/local/bin/mvim\ -f crontab -e`  Commenting because I don't have a mac to try it.

Comment: @Randy Morris: I have tried now, but escaping the space does not help either. mortinfox' solution works however.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is crontab expects to be able to run a program called "/usr/local/bin/mvim -f" if you supply that in the EDITOR environment variable.

To get around that, you could write a short shell script. For example, call this one mvimf:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/local/bin/mvim -f "$@"
```

Then you can run: EDITOR=/usr/local/bin/mvimf crontab -e

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is directly related to the problem you are having but I was seeing a similar error code when trying to edit my crontab. I realized I had a little conflict in my vimrc file related to the pathogen plugin. If you call:

```
filetype off
```

when it's already off you can cause problems that will make your Vim exit with errors. Sounds like your issue is fixed already, but since this shows up in searches related to this error code, I thought I would post it here.

Credit goes to commenters on this post - http://tooky.github.com/2010/04/08/there-was-a-problem-with-the-editor-vi-git-on-mac-os-x.html

Answer (score 1):

For those seeing this without mvim, you can use morton-fox's answer for any editor:

```
EDITOR=/usr/bin/vim crontab -e
```

Will use `vim` to open the crontab file